# "Launch screen interface file base name" zoom out application for iPhone 6/ 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c

I came up with a problem regarding my app and the new screen sizes of iPhone 6/6+. The scenario when i change orientation of a textview the keyboard is moving to the top bar and looks trimmed (not completely visible) instead of staying in the bottom.

From what i read i had to include the "Launch screen interface file base name" in my info.plist file. Which i did and indeed it solved the problem with the keyboard but it added a new issue to the app.

Now when the app is loaded it looks like zoomed out some of the screens are now in this mode.

I have added the relevant images in the images.xcassets in a New  LaunchImages but nothing has changed. What am i missing?

EDIT: forgot to mentioned that when the app is loading the Launch image started  but it is just a black screen